# import object from file where this object is imported object too. What problems may happens?

Tags: python, import

Let's decide that I have many `runner.py` files with code:

```py
from sys import argv

print(argv[0])
```

But I want to create custom `argv` for some cases, and added `custom_argv.py` wtih code:

```py
import os

if os.environ.get('HIDE_INTERPRETER_PATH') == 'TRUE':
  import sys
  argv = (['hidden_path'] + sys.argv[1:])
else:
  from sys import argv
```

And after that I changed all my `runner.py` files to:

```py
from custom_argv import argv

print(argv[0])
```

Here is no matter what happens in `if os.environ.get('HIDE_INTERPRETER_PATH') == 'TRUE'` block, because that is just simple example. Real code is different.

But I'm not sure about `else` case
`argv` is just reimported from another file. Should I expect some problems / strange behaviour with this code in future? (imported object may be changed between imports?, object initialization timing problems?, memory usage will be twice bigger?, etc... I don't know...)

Comment: Why not declare a list `args` and do all manipulations with this list? `args = (['hidden_path'] + argv[1:]) if os.environ.get('HIDE_INTERPRETER_PATH') == 'TRUE' else argv`. I personally prefer to avoid modification of any module and generally don't recommend anyone to do this unless it's the only way.

Comment: All this warnings *"it could cause unexpected behavior"* looks like overcaution until once you face this "unexpected behavior" which caused by on line of code written year ago to economy half an hour :D I have no idea how modification of `argv` could create any problems, noone has and that's the problem :D

Comment: @OlvinRoght Because original code is more complicated than example. original `argv` is a big class with own properties that used in many parts of code. `args` will be a copy of `argv` in your example but many other parts of code using (and updating) `argv` but not `args`.

Comment: Downstream code / some other module might be using the `sys.argv` and by overwriting it you do risk breaking something. But I don't think it should cause issues in terms of memory usage or any of the other things you mention

Comment: @rzlvmp, most of modern IDEs has "refactoring" functionality which allows you to rename variable in all project with two mouse clicks, so that should not be a problem at all.

Comment: @Mortz `Downstream code / some other module might be using the sys.argv and by overwriting it you do risk breaking something` → Yes. You are correct. I updated logic for `if` block. Original object is not changed in my real logic

Comment: @OlvinRoght `most of modern IDEs has "refactoring" functionality` → Yep. Here is many solutions. But I guess that this code is easy to understand and `else` case is short and clear.  As far as I know python here is no problems with re-import and adding new variable name will be just reference (link) for original class anyway. So here is no need to create new objects. But I little bit afraid of some hidden problems and want to clear this situation

Comment: @rzlvmp, as I already told in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70799223/10824407#comment125162485_70799223) comment, some minor "hacks" could potentially lead to great headache. I've used one-liner in my comment, just because it's comment and I wanted to fit working code example in it. Generally, you could firstly copy `argv` list into `args` variable (`args = argv[:]`) and then modify `args` if condition is true. By the way, first argument of args is always script path, which you can access using [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__file__).